# Android JavaCV JAR inclusion issue with OpenCV_Core

Tags: android, javacv

I get the following exception at runtime when i compile my project width static javacv.jar, opencv.jar, ffmpeg.jar and javacpp.jar files for javacv.

> 02-05 23:23:56.513    8280-8280/com.teralogics.uvlens
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.teralogics.uvlens, PID: 8280
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core
>               at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:387)
>               at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
>               at org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractArray.(opencv_core.java:126)

However, when I follow the following gradle config suggestion, it runs fine:

> compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '0.10'
>       compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.10-0.10', classifier: 'android-arm'
>       compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.5.1-0.10', classifier: 'android-arm'

So what gives? How come javacpp.Loader.load cannot find javacpp.opencv_core class definition? Do I need to include something else? I also tried specifying various combinations of file dependencies within Android Studio's project structure but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone else who may come across this issue, I was not including `arm` versions of the opencv and ffmpeg jars.